# Simply fetching data from Cloud Firestore but Firestore + ViewModel + LiveData

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-architecture-components

I'm building an app with use of Cloud Firestore. I've already implemented `RecyclerView` with `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and set to it data from collection. Before I process further I need to understand something:
1. Inversely to local database (`sqlite3`, without LiveData) `Firestore` does send a request to a device when any change in the database occurs, am I right?
2. Assuming I was right in the "question" above. When I fetch data to the adapter like this:

**In my activity `onCreate`:**

```
val questions = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("DatabaseStructure")
        val query = questions.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<DatabaseStructure>()
            .setQuery(query, DatabaseStructure::class.java)
            .build()
        firestoreAdapter = FirestoreAdapter(options)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        recyclerView.adapter = firestoreAdapter
```

**My data class:**

```
data class DatabaseStructure(
val question: String = "",
val description: String? = "",
val image: String? = "",
val leftAnswers: Int = 0,
val rightAnswers: Int = 0,
val timestamp: com.google.firebase.Timestamp = com.google.firebase.Timestamp(Date()),
val userName: String? = "Anonymous")
```

Every time activity is recreated, e.g users rotates device, reopens activity, data is fetched from the Cloud Firestore one more time, even if no changes appeared, am I right? To avoid this should I use ViewModel then?

3. Assuming question above was also true and I've implemented ViewModel to my application, that stores data from Cloud Firestore. Now if any change in the database appears, Firestore sends a request to a device to fetch data. Is there still any sense to observe data using `LiveData`?
4. To sum up, what is the best model to implement `Firestore` without unnecessary fetching data from database, to make it in the most efficient way and the least power consuming?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asking a lot here.  It's too much to address at once.  Have a look at this: https://github.com/CodingDoug/firebase-jetpack

Comment: I got the same problem. if you find the solution yourself, please post the answer